# Free jqGrid 4.8.0 - understanding of the built-in date formatter

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I'm having a date formatter that works great on miliseconds:

```
gridField.formatter = 'date';
gridField.formatoptions = {};
gridField.formatoptions['srcformat'] = 'U/1000';
gridField.formatoptions['newformat'] = 'm/d/Y H:i:s';
```

At some stage, within the osSelectRow, I do:

```
celValue = $('#'+gridName).jqGrid ('getCell', rowid, 'start_time');
```

I get all value as they should, but when I do it for dates fields, I get 'false' as the celValue.

I tried to place also unformat function but it didn't take (I suppose since this is a built in formatter).

Is there anything I'm missing here?

Comment: could you include some test data and the `colModel`. It would be better if one can reproduce the problem exactly.

Comment: Thanks Oleg,  I created an example here:  http://jsfiddle.net/mrfvsyc2/ but appears to be working (returning the date, not false).

Comment: OK, I managed to re-create the problem, it's because i'm using jsonmap instead of name, so than my question would be, if it's possible to retrieve the value based on jsonmap and not based on name?  (see http://jsfiddle.net/mrfvsyc2/1/)

Comment: I'll close this one and open a new one with the right topic/question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue.  It was due to the fact I gave jsonmap as the 'name', and used other string for the 'name' in ColModel.